# Windows 10 slow at opening external links

Tags: windows-10

Basically, if I click a link in any program, the program freezes for 60 seconds before the link opens in the default browser and the program unfreezes. I tested this 10 times (in different programs) and links consistently took 55-65 seconds to open.

This happens with any external program (that isn't a browser), whether it be a link in 'Settings', Discord, Ableton, Spotify, Mullvad, etc. It happens regardless of which browser is default (tried Edge, Firefox and Chromium). It also started happening right after a fresh install of Windows before any updates, drivers or programs were installed. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: What happens if you try it in Safe Mode?

Comment: Have you perform a clean boot and disable security software, firewall to check?
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows